# Split or duplicate records when more than 24 hours entered per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have an absence system where people are putting in their total time off instead of splitting it into different records. So my data looks like this

```
EMP_ID   |   HOURS   |   DATE  
---------|-----------|------------   
1        |    24     |  2013-10-10
2        |     8     |  2013-11-06
3        |    48     |  2013-11-13
4        |    51     |  2013-12-10
```

I need a query (this can ultimately be a stored proc) that will bring data back like so

```
    EMP_ID   |   HOURS   |   DATE
-------------|-----------|-------------
    1        |    24     |  2013-10-10
    2        |     8     |  2013-11-06
    3        |    24     |  2013-11-13
    3        |    24     |  2013-11-14
    4        |    24     |  2013-12-10
    4        |    24     |  2013-12-11
    4        |     3     |  2013-12-12
```

Notice how the day just increases by 1. Anyone who entered more than 24 hours will get their record split. Any residual is tacked on at the end as a partial day.

Lastly (I can work this on my own), I need to be careful not to cross over the year's end.

Comment: Yes, I should add that this is SQL Server. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server you can use a recursive CTE.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/acadb/2)**

```
with cte as
(
  select emp_id, 
    hours as tHours, 
    case when hours >= 24 then 24 else hours end as hours, 
    date 
  from YourTable

  UNION ALL

  select c.emp_id, 
    c.thours - (case when c.thours >= 24 then 24 else c.hours end),
    case when (c.thours - (case when c.thours >= 24 then 24 else c.hours end)) >= 24 then 24 else c.thours - 24 end, 
    dateadd(day, 1, c.date)
  from cte c
  join YourTable m on c.thours - 24 > 0 and m.emp_id = c.emp_id
)

select emp_id, 
  hours, 
  date 
from cte
order by emp_id, date
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually ended up going a different direction to solve this. Once I get the code cleaned up, I'll post my answer for posterity.
By the way, yours looks way cleaner (but I have not tested it yet)